# CSV file output reformat

Tags: linux, bash

creating a script that reads in a CSV file and reformat the output, the CSV file has five columns but my expected output result when the script is ran should be three columns. two columns were merged

This is what the CSV file:

```
Account number (preferred / formatted),Customer reference,Posting date,Account currency,Transaction amount
750856653,233413,3/9/2019,USD,-1439.58
750856653,233431,3/9/2019,USD,-186.66
750856653,NONREF,3/9/2019,USD,14401.48
```

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

input="/file-path/details.csv"
column -t -s: |
sed 's/ ,/,/g'
while IFS=',' read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5
do
echo "$f1 $f2 $f3 $f4 $f5 "
done < "$input"
```

This is my desired output:

```
750-85665-3 0000233420 090319000000209299
750-85665-3 0000233417 090319000000285615
750-85665-3 0000233426 090319000000239225
```

Comment: Comparing the input csv and the desired output, I guess the 1st field
(Account number?) is hyphenated at appropriate positions and the third
field (Posting date?) is reformatted by zero-padding. But I have no idea
where the `233420` portion and the `209299` portion in the 1st line of the desired output came from.

Comment: you are right, the first field which is the account number should be hyphenated, the date filed and transaction amount field is merged together and filled with zero's

Comment: Thank you for the response, but my question is how to calculate `233420`, `209299`, and the numbers in the following lines. I cannot figure out the way to calculate these numbers by using the provided CSV file. In addition, how you handle with the field `NONREF` in the CSV? Would you show us the algorithm or formula to obtain the amount numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tr. You translate commas with space.

```
 cat "/file-path/details.csv" | tr ',' ' '
```

If you want to delete the first line, you can use sed

```
 sed -i 1d $'/file-path/details.csv'
```

And if you want to skip the first line use tail

```
 tail -n +2 /file-path/details.csv  | tr ',' ' '
```